# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException even after all suggestion done

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I am getting below mentioned error

My current settings are:

```
opt.SyncTimeout = 100000
opt.AllowAdmin = True
opt.KeepAlive = 300000
<processModel autoConfig="false" minIoThreads="200" minWorkerThreads="200" />
```

> ```
> An unhandled exception of type 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException' occurred in StackExchange.Redis.dll
> Additional information: Timeout performing KEYS, inst: 0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 2, qu: 2, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: DESKTOP-4PP7624, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/localhost:6379, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=4090,Min=4,Max=4095) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that your minIoThreads and minWorkerThreads worked based on your error log.

Also, Keys is a very expensive call - it is O(n). Maybe try increasing the sync timeout higher?